# Where can I find more information about int % 5?

Tags: c#

I'm wondering what int id = 5%2; does exactly and also look for similar things.

Reason:

I want to calculate by a number on which row / column the item should be standing.

**[Example]**

I have a grid which is 5x5.

If id = 05, it should be on the 1st row and the 5th column

If id = 10, it should be on the 2nd row and the 5th column

If id = 12, it should be on the 3rd row and the 2nd column

How you catch my drift!

*(ps: feel free to edit my tags. Not sure what to put on this question)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modulus (`%` in some C-derivative languages) is the remainder left over when one number is divided by another. So `38 % 6` is `2` (`38 / 6` is `6` with a remainder of `2`).

It's typically used for exactly the sort of thing you're asking about. If your 5x5 grid is:

```
    col  1  2  3  4  5
row
 1       1  2  3  4  5
 2       6  7  8  9 10
 3      11 12 13 14 15
 4      16 17 18 19 20
 5      21 22 23 24 25
```

then the row can be calculated as `(x-1)/5+1` (that's integer division rather than floating point) and the column as `(x-1)%5+1`:

```
 x   (x-1)/5+1   (x-1)%5+1
--   ---------   ---------
 5       1           5
10       2           5
12       3           2
```

The reason you initially subtract the one and then add it on is because modulus works best on zero-based numbers while yours are one-based. The subtract/add is to turn your scheme into zero-based before performing the modulus, then turning it back into one-based afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

`%` is the [Modulus Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx), or in more common terms the remainder. So `5%2` would give you an id of `1`. Using this you can calculate the `row` and `column` values in your grid. So for example

```
id = 5;
column = (id - 1)%5 + 1;
row = (id - 1)/5 + 1;
```

The `- 1` is because you seem to start off your rows at `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: If id == 5 => row = 0 and column = 4. In example they are 1 and 5